Can there be a function which is holomorphic in the annulus $1 < |z| < 4$ and whos real part is $ln(x^2+y^2)?$
The function $u=ln(x^2+y^2)$ seems to be harmonic everywhere except at the origin. So in every simply connected domain that doesn't include that point, it probably has a harmonic conjugate.
However I'm trying to answer the question whether there can be a function which is holomorphic in the annulus $1<|z|<4$ and whos real part is u as defined above.
The annulus that we are looking at is not simply connected, I think, so the existence of a harmonic conjugate of u is not guaranteed, and considering the way the question is formulated, maybe there is reason to believe that a harmonic conjugate can't exist.
Does anyone know what reason that could be?
EDIT: This is not a duplicate of the question that has been mentioned by a moderator since that question concerns another function. Please observe the difference.

Apart from the factor $1/2$ (and the notation $\ln$ instead of $\log$ for the logarithm) your question looks identical to the duplicate target to me. Am I missing something?
